desktop7:Logo with ico file in appx manifest doesn't work
My Windows Store application defines a file type association using this code in the appx manifest:
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
        <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="something">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
                <uap:FileType ContentType="application/vnd.company.something">.something</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
                        
            <uap:DisplayName>Something</uap:DisplayName>
            <uap:EditFlags OpenIsSafe="true" />
            <desktop7:Logo>app\resources\File.ico</desktop7:Logo>
        </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>

The files are correctly associated with my app, but the icon does not appear in the Windows File Explorer; the files get a generic blank icon instead.

I understand that I could convert my ICO to a set of PNGs and use uap:Logo instead of desktop7:Logo. But I would still like to know:
What am I doing wrong? Or have I found a bug in Windows?
